# Convert array of doubles to bytearray in Java

Tags: java, udp, double, arrays

In past I haven't done much of byte shifting so I'm a bit loss here. Basically I have double array of size 26 and I should send the array in one UDP packet in Java. I found some examples of how to convert one double to bytearray, but I'm not sure how to apply it to double-array.

So how this should be done? Loop through the double array and convert each double and somehow concatenating them to one bytearray?

Comment: I think you want to start with reading about [`DoubleBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html). Better yet, start with the method [ByteBuffer#asDoubleBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asDoubleBuffer())

Comment: If you know how to do it once and have to do it 26 times, why no use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how this should be done? Loop through the double array and convert each double and somehow concatenating them to one bytearray?

Exactly. You can make use of DoubleBuffer, perhaps. (Marko linked it in his comment)

What Marko referred to was having actually a ByteBuffer and fetching a "DoubleBuffer"-View to it. So you can `put` the Doubles into the DoubleBuffer View and fetch the byte[] from the original ByteBuffer.

Comment: I always thought about java.nio being rather low-level, but it is much more .. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O - thanks to Fildor

Comment: Ah, bytebuffer was exactly what I was missing here! Thanks for you and Marko for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

Convert your doubles into a byte array using java.nio.ByteBuffer

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(doubles.length * 8);
for(double d : doubles) {
   bb.putDouble(d);
}
```

get the byte array

```
byte[] bytearray = bb.array();
```

send it over the net and then convert it to double array on the receiving side

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytearray);
double[] doubles = new double(bytearray.length / 8);
for(int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
    doubles[i] = bb.getDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

apache httpcore provides a **org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer** class which my be helpful

```
ByteArrayBuffer buffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(26);
buffer.append(...)
```