# "base64-encoded little-endian doubles" in java

Tags: java, base64, quantum-computing, dwave

I am currently trying to use java to create requests for the DWave solvers.
At the moment I am trying to wrap my head around the JSON-encoding part. Especially how the parameters of the problem are to be transmitted.

The description just reads:
base64-encoded little-endian doubles (see https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/c_rest_api_5.html)
which is only little info. To try and get info I tried to decode the String in the example. (The one starting with AAAAAAAA4L8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+H+amZmZmZnJP....).
Trying to decode it made only a IllegalArgumentException, or when shortening the String it sometimes returned some gibberish.

Does anyone have an idea how this works?

(I tried to look at the ocean-sdk source code however I'm not good enough at python to read it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the documentation contains multiple base64-encoded lines:

```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==
```

The first line decodes to the following:

```bash
$ printf 'AAAAAAAA4L8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+H+amZmZmZnJPwAAAAAAAPh/AAAAAAAA+H8A' | base64 -d | xxd
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 e0bf 0000 0000 0000 f03f  ...............?
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 f87f  ................
00000020: 9a99 9999 9999 c93f 0000 0000 0000 f87f  .......?........
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 f87f 00                   .........
```

A double comprises 8 octets, so the first double value is `0000 0000 0000 e0bf`. Interpreting this as an IEEE 754 floating-point double gives you: `2.8426e-319`.

The line breaks have to be removed to give you the full base64-encoded input. I don't think the line breaks are required when serializing, but you can simply add them *after* you have encoded as base64 (if they are missing).

To encode an array of doubles, you have to first [convert to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16892580/112968) which can then be fed to the Base64 encoder.

Parsing the full base64 string will give you 128 double values:

```bash
$ printf 'AAAAAAAA4L8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+H+amZmZmZnJPwAAAAAAAPh/AAAAAAAA+H8A
AAAAAAD4fwAAAAAAAPh/AAAAAAAA+H8AAAAAAAD4fwAAAAAAAPh/AAAAAAAA+H8AAAAAAAD4fwAA
....
AAAAAAD4fwAAAAAAAPh/AAAAAAAA+H8AAAAAAAD4fwAAAAAAAPh/AAAAAAAA+H8AAAAAAAD4fw==' | base64 -d | xxd -p -c0 | fold -w16
000000000000e0bf
000000000000f03f
0000000000000000
000000000000f87f
9a9999999999c93f
000000000000f87f
000000000000f87f
# ... value repeated ...
000000000000f87f
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll continue investigating how to encode my data from there!

Comment: @NumericPrime I have added a link how to convert doubles to bytes. Hope that helps